# Fastify calling controller method multiple times when multiple preHandler hook is called

Tags: node.js, fastify

I have a fastify route method with the following schema.

`fastify.post('/club', createClubSchema, createClub(fastify));`

```
const createClubSchema = {
    schema: {
        tags: ['club'],
        security: [
            {
                ApiKeyAuth: [],
            },
        ],
        body: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['name', 'description'],
            properties: {
                name: { type: 'string', minLength: 3 },
                description: { type: 'string', minLength: 3 },
                logoUrl: { type: 'string', minLength: 3 },
            },
        },
        response: {
            200: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    status: { type: 'string' },
                    data: {
                        type: 'object',
                        properties: {
                            name: { type: 'string' },
                            description: { type: 'string' },
                            id: { type: 'number' },
                            color: { type: 'string' },
                            logoUrl: { type: 'string' },
                            createdAt: { type: 'string' },
                            updatedAt: { type: 'string' },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    preHandler: [grantAccess('create', 'club')],
};
```

Now this route is in folder where there is `autohooks.js` is located that has a prehandler hook of it's own which checks whether the request has token in it for authentication purposes.

The problem is after the `preHandler` hook is called on both the area the `createClub` controller method is called, so a total of 2 times.

What is the issue? and how can i solve this?

### EDIT

This is the `autoHooks.js` file
const authentication = require('../../middlewares/authentication');

```
module.exports = async function (fastify, opts, next) {
    fastify.addHook('preHandler', authentication.authenticate(fastify));
};
```

Comment: Dont mix `async` and `next`. Choose one and it should solve

Comment: if you've created an async auth strategy decorator, you should not call done() at the end. [See this github issue](https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/636#issuecomment-1049635901)

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon can you please give me the link to where this is mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: It is standard javascript code - you create a race condition when you use async + callback style together. don't do it.